# emsdk with Qt creator. Problem with PATH and compile program

Tags: python, windows, qt, emsdk

Hello my problem is with instalation emsdk on qt creator on Windows.
I did

```
> git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git
> emsdk install 3.1.25 # (for my Qt 6.5.3)
> emsdk activate 3.1.25
```

Why my Qt creator don't see path:

```
Adding directories to PATH:
C:\Users\oliwi\OneDrive\Pulpit\Michal\emsdk\python\3.9.2-nuget_64bit
Setting environment variables:
EMSDK_NODE=C:\Users\oliwi\OneDrive\Pulpit\Michal\emsdk\node\16.20.0_64bit\bin\node.exe
EMSDK_PYTHON=C:\Users\oliwi\OneDrive\Pulpit\Michal\emsdk\python\3.9.2-nuget_64bit\python.exe
JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\oliwi\OneDrive\Pulpit\Michal\emsdk\java\8.152_64bit
```

I have installed Python and added to enviroments variables my emsdk and python.
I did sudo chmod -R 777 emsdk

```
em++ --version
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 3.1.25 (165133b1cc977f0b9a277e42ef809b823157189c)
Copyright (C) 2014 the Emscripten authors (see AUTHORS.txt)
This is free and open source software under the MIT license.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I've seen tutorials did 1:1 and have same problems.